# Attempting to query all Windows servers to find those that have media loaded in the CD-ROM drive

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a command to query all Windows servers in AD and report if they have media loaded in the CD-ROM drive. I pieced together a command that I thought was correct and now I'm stuck at it reporting and RPC error. Note: The CD-ROM drive does not have the same assigned drive letter on every server.

Command:

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"'
foreach($Computer in $Computers){GET-WmiObject –query 'SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk where DriveType = "5"' –computername $Computer | Select Displayname,DeviceID,Size,VolumeName}

I receive the following error when executing it.

GET-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.
At line:2 char:34

- ... $Computers){GET-WmiObject –query 'SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk whe ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

I've never used the Get-WmiObject command before and I'm in unfamiliar territory. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try `–computername $Computer.Name`.  (You may need firewall / endpoint configuration changes on your servers to allow remote WMI queries; it may be worth trying get-ciminstance or invoke-command)

Comment: Thanks Heckler, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks again Heckler. Simply adding the .Name corrected it. I shouldn't have missed that.

Comment: @Nataka great! I've put it as a proper answer just to be tidy.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AdComputer` doesn't return computer *names* you can use directly with `-ComputerName`, try:

```
–computername $Computer.Name
```